# In Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 how do I show only a single "read more" to show a 2-column list using the 'shorten" JS plugin

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 with CSS (and do not wish to use SASS). I'm running Windows 7. I'm using Jquery Shorten to display a list of languages https://github.com/viralpatel/jquery.shorten

I am trying to reduce from featuring two "read more" to just a single "read more" (preferably keeping the one on the right. See screenshot below:

[image]

This is my html:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <ul class="noindent">
      <li>Albanian transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Amharic transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Arakanese transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Armenian transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Azerbaijani transcription and translation</li>
    </ul>
 <div>
    <ul class="comment-small noindent">
      <li>Aymara transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Belarusan transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Bengali transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Bhilali transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Burmese transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Cambodian transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Caqchiquel transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Chechen transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Creole transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Dari transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Dinka transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Faroese transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Farsi transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Flemish transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Fujianese transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Fulani transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Georgian transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Uzbek transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Greenlandic transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Guarani transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Gujerati transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Hassaniya transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Fujianese transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Icelandic transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Inuktitut transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Kazahk transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Khmer transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Kinyarwanda transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Lingala transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Maasai transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Macedonian transcription and translation</li>
      <li>Malay transcription and translation</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <ul class="noindent">

    <li>Marathi transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Mongolian transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Nepali transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Ossetian transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Papiamentu transcription and translation</li>
    </ul>
 <div>
   <ul class="comment-small noindent">  
    <li>Pashto transcription and translation</li> 
    <li>Kazahk transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Khmer transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Kinyarwanda transcription and translation</li>    
    <li>Lingala transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Maasai transcription and translation</li>    
    <li>Macedonian transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Malay transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Marathi transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Mongolian transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Nepali transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Ossetian transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Papiamentu transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Pashto transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Quechua transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Samoan transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Shanghaiese transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Shona transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Sinhalese transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Somali transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Swahili transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Taiwanese transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Tajik transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Tamil transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Telugu transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Tibetan transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Tzutuhil transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Urdu transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Vietnamese transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Wolof transcription and translation</li>
    <li>Yoruba transcription and translation</li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

     </div>
```

I have this fiddle showing the 2-column list https://jsfiddle.net/setbon/b124wsrk/

Comment: Based on a suggestion I received I created an updated fiddle but unfortunately still does not perform desired action. https://jsfiddle.net/setbon/tf7Lkdc0/1/